# Buliding an ARM cross-compiler with crosstool-ng on OS X

Tags: macos, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to create a cross compiler on my Mac for my Raspberry Pi, I have managed to configure, build and install crosstool-ng, but when building the `arm-unknow-linux-gnueabi` toolchain, it fails. The output of `./ct-ng build` is:

```
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20140517.143156
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Dumping user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@216]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@125]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.19.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:00.00)
[00:00] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

The contents of my `build.log` are:

```
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -n  )'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'mkdir' '-p' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build' 
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'rm' '-f' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/backtrace' 
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'touch' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/foo' 
[DEBUG]  Testing '! ( -f /Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/FOO )'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'rm' '-f' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/foo' 
[DEBUG]  Testing '-f /bin/bash -a -x /bin/bash'
[DEBUG]  Creating bin-override for tools in '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'mkdir' '-p' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'install' -> '"/usr/bin/install -c"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/install' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'bash' -> '"/bin/bash"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/bash' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'awk' -> '"/usr/local/bin/awk"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/awk' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'grep' -> '"/usr/bin/grep"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/grep' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'make' -> '"/usr/bin/make"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/make' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'sed' -> '"/usr/local/bin/sed"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/sed' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'libtool' -> '"/usr/local/bin/libtool"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/libtool' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'libtoolize' -> '"/usr/local/bin/libtoolize"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/libtoolize' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'objcopy' -> '"/usr/local/bin/objcopy"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/objcopy' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'objdump' -> '"/usr/local/bin/objdump"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/objdump' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'readelf' -> '"/usr/local/bin/readelf"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/readelf' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'patch' -> '"/usr/bin/patch"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/patch' 
[DEBUG]  Creating script-override for 'gperf' -> '"/usr/bin/gperf"'
[DEBUG]  ==> Executing: 'chmod' '700' '/Volumes/crosstool/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/usr/local/bin/.build/tools/bin/gperf' 
[INFO ]  Build started 20140517.161844
[DEBUG]  =================================================================
[DEBUG]  Dumping user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'grep' '-E' '^(# |)CT_' '.config' 
[DEBUG]    grep: empty (sub)expression
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Dumping user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@216]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@125]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.19.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:00.00)
```

## Update 1:

I have run `'grep' '-E' '^(# |)CT_' '.config'` in my crosstool-ng's bin directory and it returns:

```
CT_CONFIGURE_has_svn=y
CT_MODULES=y
# CT_OBSOLETE is not set
# CT_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
# CT_DEBUG_CT is not set
CT_LOCAL_TARBALLS_DIR="${HOME}/src"
CT_SAVE_TARBALLS=y
CT_WORK_DIR="${CT_TOP_DIR}/.build"
CT_PREFIX_DIR="${HOME}/x-tools/${CT_TARGET}"
CT_INSTALL_DIR="${CT_PREFIX_DIR}"
CT_RM_RF_PREFIX_DIR=y
# CT_REMOVE_DOCS is not set
# CT_BUILD_MANUALS is not set
CT_INSTALL_DIR_RO=y
CT_STRIP_ALL_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES=y
# CT_FORBID_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_FORCE_DOWNLOAD is not set
CT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10
# CT_ONLY_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_USE_MIRROR is not set
# CT_FORCE_EXTRACT is not set
CT_OVERIDE_CONFIG_GUESS_SUB=y
# CT_ONLY_EXTRACT is not set
CT_PATCH_BUNDLED=y
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_FALLBACK_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_FALLBACK_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_NONE is not set
CT_PATCH_ORDER="bundled"
CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=0
CT_LOAD=""
CT_USE_PIPES=y
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_SH is not set
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_ASH is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL_BASH=y
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_CUSTOM is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL="${bash}"
# CT_LOG_ERROR is not set
# CT_LOG_WARN is not set
# CT_LOG_INFO is not set
CT_LOG_EXTRA=y
# CT_LOG_ALL is not set
# CT_LOG_DEBUG is not set
CT_LOG_LEVEL_MAX="EXTRA"
# CT_LOG_SEE_TOOLS_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_PROGRESS_BAR=y
CT_LOG_TO_FILE=y
CT_LOG_FILE_COMPRESS=y
CT_ARCH="arm"
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_ENDIAN=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_32=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_ARCH=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_CPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_TUNE=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FLOAT=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_SOFTFP=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_HAS_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_LE=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_32=y
CT_ARCH_ARCH=""
CT_ARCH_CPU=""
CT_ARCH_TUNE=""
CT_ARCH_FPU=""
# CT_ARCH_BE is not set
CT_ARCH_LE=y
CT_ARCH_32=y
CT_ARCH_BITNESS=32
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_HW is not set
CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SW=y
CT_TARGET_CFLAGS=""
CT_TARGET_LDFLAGS=""
# CT_ARCH_alpha is not set
CT_ARCH_arm=y
# CT_ARCH_avr32 is not set
# CT_ARCH_blackfin is not set
# CT_ARCH_m68k is not set
# CT_ARCH_mips is not set
# CT_ARCH_powerpc is not set
# CT_ARCH_s390 is not set
# CT_ARCH_sh is not set
# CT_ARCH_sparc is not set
# CT_ARCH_x86 is not set
CT_ARCH_alpha_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_arm_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_avr32_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_blackfin_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_m68k_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_microblaze_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_mips_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_powerpc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_s390_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sh_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sparc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_x86_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_SUFFIX=""
# CT_MULTILIB is not set
CT_ARCH_USE_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_ENDIAN="little"
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SOFTFP is not set
CT_ARCH_FLOAT="soft"
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE="arm"
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_ARM=y
# CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_THUMB is not set
# CT_ARCH_ARM_INTERWORKING is not set
CT_ARCH_ARM_EABI_FORCE=y
CT_ARCH_ARM_EABI=y
CT_FORCE_SYSROOT=y
CT_USE_SYSROOT=y
CT_SYSROOT_NAME="sysroot"
CT_SYSROOT_DIR_PREFIX=""
# CT_STATIC_TOOLCHAIN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_PKGVERSION=""
CT_TOOLCHAIN_BUGURL=""
CT_TARGET_VENDOR="unknown"
CT_TARGET_ALIAS_SED_EXPR=""
CT_TARGET_ALIAS=""
CT_CROSS=y
# CT_CANADIAN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_TYPE="cross"
CT_BUILD=""
CT_BUILD_PREFIX=""
CT_BUILD_SUFFIX=""
# CT_TOOLCHAIN_ENABLE_NLS is not set
CT_KERNEL_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS=y
CT_KERNEL="linux"
CT_KERNEL_VERSION="3.10.2"
# CT_KERNEL_bare_metal is not set
CT_KERNEL_linux=y
CT_KERNEL_bare_metal_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_linux_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_V_3_10=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_9 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_8 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_7 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_6 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_5 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_4 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_3 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_2 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_0 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_39 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_38 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_37 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_36 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_33 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_32 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_31 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_27 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_CUSTOM is not set
CT_KERNEL_windows_AVAILABLE=y
CT_SHARED_LIBS=y
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_0=y
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_2 is not set
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSE_LEVEL=0
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_INSTALL_CHECK=y
CT_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF=y
CT_BINUTILS="binutils"
CT_BINUTILS_binutils=y
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_22 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_53 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_20_1a is not set
CT_BINUTILS_V_2_19_1a=y
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_18a is not set
CT_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.19.1a"
CT_BINUTILS_2_19_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_18_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_BINUTILS_GOLD_SUPPORTS_ARCH=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_BINUTILS_FORCE_LD_BFD=y
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD=y
CT_BINUTILS_LINKERS_LIST="ld"
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_DEFAULT="bfd"
CT_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET=y
CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET_IBERTY=y
CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET_BFD=y
CT_CC="gcc"
CT_CC_VERSION="4.3.2"
CT_CC_CORE_PASSES_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_gcc=y
# CT_CC_GCC_SHOW_LINARO is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_8_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_8_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_7 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_3 is not set
CT_CC_V_4_3_2=y
# CT_CC_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_2 is not set
CT_CC_GCC_4_2_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_3=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_3_or_later=y
# CT_CC_GCC_USE_GRAPHITE is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_USE_LTO is not set
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GMP_MPFR=y
CT_CC_LANG_JAVA_USE_ECJ=y
CT_CC_LANG_FORTRAN=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_FORTRAN=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_JAVA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_ADA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJC=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJCXX=y
CT_CC_LANG_CXX=y
CT_CC_LANG_JAVA=y
CT_CC_ENABLE_CXX_FLAGS=""
CT_CC_CORE_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_CC_GCC_SYSTEM_ZLIB is not set
CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_TARGET_OPTSPACE=y
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBMUDFLAP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSSP is not set
CT_CC_CXA_ATEXIT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DISABLE_PCH is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LDBL_128=m
CT_LIBC="glibc"
CT_LIBC_VERSION="2.9"
# CT_LIBC_eglibc is not set
CT_LIBC_glibc=y
# CT_LIBC_uClibc is not set
CT_LIBC_eglibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_glibc_AVAILABLE=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_17 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_16_0 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_15 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_13 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_2 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_10_1 is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_9=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_8 is not set
CT_LIBC_mingw_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_newlib_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_none_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_uClibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_ANY=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_NPTL=y
CT_THREADS="nptl"
CT_THREADS_NPTL=y
CT_LIBC_XLDD=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MAY_FORCE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_glibc_familly=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_CONFIGPARMS=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
CT_LIBC_EXTRA_CC_ARGS=""
# CT_LIBC_DISABLE_VERSIONING is not set
CT_LIBC_OLDEST_ABI=""
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_FORCE_UNWIND is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_USE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_ADDONS_LIST=""
# CT_LIBC_LOCALES is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_NONE is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_AS_HEADERS=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_CHOSEN is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL="3.10.2"
CT_DEBUG_dmalloc=y
CT_DMALLOC_V_5_5_2=y
CT_DMALLOC_VERSION="5.5.2"
CT_DEBUG_duma=y
CT_DUMA_A=y
CT_DUMA_SO=y
CT_DUMA_V_2_5_15=y
CT_DUMA_VERSION="2_5_15"
CT_DEBUG_gdb=y
CT_GDB_CROSS=y
# CT_GDB_CROSS_STATIC is not set
# CT_GDB_CROSS_SIM is not set
CT_GDB_CROSS_PYTHON=y
CT_GDB_CROSS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_GDB_NATIVE=y
# CT_GDB_NATIVE_STATIC is not set
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER=y
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_STATIC=y
# CT_DEBUG_GDB_SHOW_LINARO is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_2a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0a is not set
CT_GDB_V_6_8a=y
CT_GDB_VERSION="6.8a"
CT_DEBUG_ltrace=y
CT_LTRACE_V_0_5_3=y
# CT_LTRACE_V_0_5_2 is not set
CT_LTRACE_VERSION="0.5.3"
CT_LTRACE_0_5_3_or_later=y
CT_DEBUG_strace=y
# CT_STRACE_V_4_5_20 is not set
CT_STRACE_V_4_5_19=y
# CT_STRACE_V_4_5_18 is not set
CT_STRACE_VERSION="4.5.19"
CT_COMPLIBS_NEEDED=y
CT_GMP_NEEDED=y
CT_MPFR_NEEDED=y
CT_COMPLIBS=y
CT_GMP=y
CT_MPFR=y
CT_LIBELF_TARGET=y
# CT_GMP_V_5_1_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_1 is not set
CT_GMP_V_4_3_2=y
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_0 is not set
CT_GMP_VERSION="4.3.2"
# CT_MPFR_V_3_1_2 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_1_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_0 is not set
CT_MPFR_V_2_4_2=y
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_0 is not set
CT_MPFR_VERSION="2.4.2"
CT_LIBELF_V_0_8_13=y
# CT_LIBELF_V_0_8_12 is not set
CT_LIBELF_VERSION="0.8.13"
# CT_COMPLIBS_CHECK is not set
```

Please help, I'm totally clueless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it! Crosstool-ng was using its own grep (strange, I know), so I deleted its own grep (which cannot process the regular expression), and added a symlink to the GNU grep that I built and is located in `usr/local/bin/grep`.

Comment: I wouldn't have ever figured that out... would have  just bought another pi

Comment: You sure about that?  What leads you to believe that it's using its own grep?

Comment: I can't specifically remember, but I know that crosstool-ng had a directory containing build system executables (or symlinks to them) such as grep, sed, make, etc.. and it must have picked up the OS X System's BSD `grep` in `/usr/bin/grep` instead of the GNU `grep` I installed in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: For future reference, there is a `grep` at `${CT_TOP_DIR}/.build/tools/bin/grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message but came to a different diagnosis and fixed it in a completely different way.  I'm not sure who was right but I'll share my experience in hopes that it helps someone else.

After much searching I came to the conclusion that ct-ng was using the system grep which didn't have all the features that the Linux grep has and that ct-ng expected.  My solution was to use the Homebrew package manager to install the linux grep and have it override the system grep.

The steps that I took:

1. Install Hombrew using the instructions located at brew.sh
2. Type `brew install grep --with-default-names` at a terminal prompt.  The `--with-default-names` flag tells Homebrew to override the system grep.  (otherwise it would have installed it as "ggrep" to avoid confusion)  This doesn't actually delete you system grep, so if you uninstall the Hombrew grep the system grep will still be there.

After doing this the error disappeared and I was able to continue with compiling crosstool-ng.

Comment: I think we must have encountered the same sort of error, except I don't use home-brew, macports, fink, or any sort package manager and looking back on my answer I didn't really know what I was on about and phrased it very badly. I hope my other comment clears up any confusion.

Comment: That's understandable. Hopefully between your answer and my answer people will be able to figure things out.

Comment: Of course, just to add to the hair pulling, crosstool-NG has now removed --with-defaut-names in 20, so you have to add the libexec/gnubin in the the Cellar package to your path.

Answer (score 0):

A number of sites advise special treatment of grep and gettext, e.g. here:

*http://will-tm.com/cross-compiling-mac-os-x-mavericks/*

> A few things before installing crosstool-ng

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install gettext
brew edit crosstool-ng
```

> add this line to the depends section:

```
depends_on 'grep' => '--default-names'"
```